# MacOS - Uninstalling application installed on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, installation, uninstall, login-items

I'm new to Mac and mostly been working on Windows. In Windows when I installed an app downloaded from the internet, to uninstall it I simply go to the control panel and I have "Add/Remove Programs" where I see all installed apps and can remove any app I've installed.

I've installed an app on my Mac (Focusrite Control) - I've downloaded the dmg from the Focusrite site and inside there was an installer (it was an installation wizard). I see that it was not what I've expected so I wish to remove it.
How do I uninstall a program that was installed in that way?

I followed their uninstall instructions here: https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115003235785-How-to-fully-uninstall-Focusrite-Control-from-your-computer

I removed the app from the Applications folder and also deleted the files that did exist on the location they specified (not all of the files they mentioned were present).
But, under `Settings > General > Login Items > Allow in the Background` I still have in the list there `FocusriteControlServer`. How do I remove that?

And how do I know that this is it and that's all there is to remove from an installation? And what is the correct way to uninstall software from Mac?

Comment: Usually deleting the application from the Applications folder will suffice. After you followed the steps from their site, did you restart your laptop?

Comment: Yes. I've restarted my Mac - even with full shutdown and powering back up - but I still see it in the Background Services.

Comment: If you have done that and the AppCleaner doesn't work, you can open up the Activity Monitor and try to find any process related to Focusrite. Then double click on it and check Open Files and Ports tab, to see if you can reveal the locations that you need to delete.

Answer (score 1):

If an app was installed by just dragging & dropping from a .dmg file, then simply deleting it from Applications is enough. The same applies to apps from the App Store.

This does leave bits behind, but they will be tiny & not interfere with the operation of the Mac in future.

Apps that use an actual installer package do so because they need to insert 'extras' into the system - like .dlls on Windows.
Those apps *should* come with an appropriate uninstaller - however, as you've discovered, some don't.
Sometimes developers will provide a list of items to remove manually to uninstall. Removing these will often require a reboot afterwards, as until then startup items may remain in the Mac's launch structure & not be re-evaluated until next boot.

There is a freeware app, [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware), that will attempt to find these & other 'stray' files & delete them for you. You just drop the app onto it & let it search.

In short, a reboot ought to clear your 'stray' launch item. If not, then drag the app back from the Trash & try dropping it onto AppCleaner.